# React-datasheet editorDialog closed by dropDown click without tigger onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use [react-datasheet](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet) `table` to show a matrix/grid of data. I did overwrite the [dataEditor](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#data-editor) to open a custom dialog where you can only select preselected values, from a [material-ui dropdown](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#selects). But if you select a value from dropdown the dialog, the dialog will be close without triggering `onChange` function.

I did rebuild the issue in a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-moon-4cfe3

> If I use native dropdown I can select a value and my `onChange` function will be triggered:
>
> `<Select native onChange={handleChange} value={currentValue}>` in `src/components/EditorDialog.js:17`

Comment: Even `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.preventDefault()` don't seem to help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is a solution that should get rid of all the problems which are caused by using the `Material UI Select` inside `ReactDataSheet`.

I did extract the `EditorDialog` so it is rendered below the `ReactDataSheet` and therefore does not trigger the `onMouseDown` event of the `cell`.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

> You can use `onClose` without parameters inside the `EditorDialog` to close the dialog!

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDataSheet from 'react-datasheet'

import EditorDialog from './EditorDialog'

export default class Datasheet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      editorProps: null,
      grid: [[{ value: 1 }, { value: 3 }], [{ value: 2 }, { value: 4 }]]
    }
  }

  handleDataEditor: Function = editorProps => {
    this.setState({ editorProps })

    if (!editorProps) {
      return null
    }

    return <span>{editorProps.value}</span>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ReactDataSheet
          data={this.state.grid}
          // ...
          dataEditor={this.handleDataEditor}
        />
        <EditorDialog {...editorProps} onClose={this.handleDataEditor} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Great ! This is straightforward, I've also tried to add some conditional check in `onMouseDown` event as well as trying to use `ReactDOM.createPortal` for `EditorDialog` component, but none of them worked. Guess the best bet is to render the `EditorDialog` as a separate component like you did ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found the issue after 2 hours.

### Datasheet.js

In your **Datasheet.js**, the issue was because of the `onMouseDown` event callback handler in your cell. Removing it will fix the `onChange` not triggering in `Select` component issue.

#### Bonus:

I've copied the `onCellsChanged` callback handler from [here](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#basic-usage) directly.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDataSheet from "react-datasheet";

import EditorDialog from "./EditorDialog";

export default class Datasheet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grid: [[{ value: 1 }, { value: 3 }], [{ value: 2 }, { value: 4 }]]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ReactDataSheet
          data={this.state.grid}
          // Copied from https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#basic-usage
          onCellsChanged={changes => {
            const grid = this.state.grid.map(row => [...row])
            changes.forEach(({cell, row, col, value}) => {
              grid[row][col] = {...grid[row][col], value}
            })
            this.setState({ grid })
          }}
          valueRenderer={cell => cell.value}
          // The issue was because of the onMouseDown callback
          cellRenderer={({ onDoubleClick, children, className }) => {
            return (
              <td onDoubleClick={onDoubleClick} className={className}>
                {children}
              </td>
            )
          }}
          dataEditor={EditorDialog}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### EditorDialog.js

In your **EditorDialog.js**, you actually don't need internal state, unless the components behaves like a form ( Ex: With inputs, confirmation / cancel buttons ). I've added some comments inside the codes as well. Slightly modified the code examples that you've given. You can use `onCommit` callback instead of using `onChange` as usually its a click to decide the value ( Not a textfield input ). You can read more about `dataEditor` props available options [here](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#data-editor)

```
import React from "react";
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";

import "../styles.css";

// Bonus: You can get your current editing cell value inside your props directly,
// instead of using `cell.value`
export default function EditorDialog({ onCommit, value }) {
  // You actually don't need internal state here, unless it behaves like a form.

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value: newValue } = event.target;
    // Calling onCommit will close the Select and
    // call `onCellsChanged` callback in React Datasheet.
    onCommit(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Dialog">
      <Select onChange={handleChange} value={value}>
        <option value="" />
        <option value={1}>1</option>
        <option value={2}>2</option>
        <option value={3}>3</option>
        <option value={4}>4</option>
        <option value={5}>5</option>
        <option value={6}>6</option>
        <option value={7}>7</option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that now the cell cannot be selected and will not get the class `selected` so the `onMouseDown` is necessary for this. Do you have any Idea on how to make cell selection working again with your solution?

Comment: @Vl4dimyr Yes. It did removes the necessary event listener for drag selection. I have not find a solution that saves the `onMouseDown` event handler and also the `onChange` not triggering issue yet. I am assuming that it is not necessary at this point because it is using `select` as the `Editor` component.